# How to return an Optional from MyBatis query

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Is there any way to get MyBatis to return an `Optional<MyClass>` instance rather than simply a `MyClass` instance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Mybatis pre 3.5.0

Create custom [ObjectFactory](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#objectFactory) like this:

```
class OptionalAwareObjectFactory extends DefaultObjectFactory {

  public Object create(Class type, List<Class> constructorArgTypes, List<Object> constructorArgs) {
     if (Optional.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
        return Optional.fromNullable(Iterables.getOnlyElement(constructorArgs));
     } else {
        return super.create(type, constructorArgTypes, constructorArgs);
     }
  }
}
```

And configure it to be used in `mybatis.xml`:

```
 <objectFactory type="my.company.project.OptionalAwareObjectFactory"/>
```

### Mybatis 3.5.0+

Since 3.5.0 `Optional` is supported natively as [fankai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5207332/fankai) pointed out.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

Mybatis supports Optional return type officially now since 3.5.0, refer to http://blog.mybatis.org/2019/01/mybatis-350-released.html

Not sure how Roman's answer worked ... it might work in earlier version of Mybatis, as the method signature suggests, but apparently doesn't work with latest versions.